# If statement not updating a private field in the same class

Tags: java, if-statement

so I have this code from class:

```
private int velocity = 0;

public void velocityManagement(int speed){
        if (speed > 0){
            System.out.println("Pressing gas pedal");
            velocity += speed;
            System.out.println("Velocity increased to " + velocity + " km/h");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Pressing break");
            velocity -= speed;
            System.out.println("Velocity decreased to " + velocity + " km/h");
        }
```

That's how I use it in the main class:

```
car.velocityManagement(10);
car.velocityManagement(15);
car.velocityManagement(-20);
```

> Expected output:

- Pressing gas pedal
- Velocity increased to 10 km/h
- Pressing gas pedal
- Velocity increased to 25 km/h
- Pressing break
- Velocity decreased to 5 km/h

> Actual output:

- Pressing gas pedal
- Velocity increased to 10 km/h
- Pressing gas pedal
- Velocity increased to 25 km/h
- Pressing break
- Velocity decreased to 45 km/h

Comment: @WojtekT missclick when I clicked the tag. Sorry

Comment: Because of minus minus...

Comment: Do always: velocity += speed; because 10 + -10 = 0 ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're substracting a negative number when the speed is negative, that's the same thing as adding a positive number:

```
// When speed is negative, this corresponds to adding 
// the absolute value of speed to velocity
velocity -= speed;
```

You should add this negative number instead. Only the print statement should be on the `if else` statement.

```
public void velocityManagement(int speed){
        if (speed > 0){
            System.out.println("Pressing gas pedal");
            System.out.println("Velocity increased to " + velocity + " km/h");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Pressing break");
            System.out.println("Velocity decreased to " + velocity + " km/h");
        }
        velocity += speed;
}
```

Best